# How to correct problem with ybar plot: bad axis and too many labels in x axis

Tags: pgfplots

I need a bit of help here with the axis... Any suggestions would be always welcome. I have got 2 extra labels at the x axis...

```
 \documentclass{scrreprt}

 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgflibrary{decorations.markings}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri     }
 \usepackage{textcomp}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 symbolic x coords={AL2O3, ALN, Si3N4, BeO, Epoxid, Polimid, ALSiC, Al, Cu,      Mo, Si, Au},
 width=15cm,
 height=5cm,
 %xtick={200,400},
 %grid=major,
 x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
 ylabel=$\mathbf{W/m\cdot K}$,
 enlargelimits=0.15,
 legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
 anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
 ybar=5pt,% configures `bar shift'
 ymin=0,
 ymax=500,
 bar width=0.4cm,
 nodes near coords,
 ]
 \addplot[color=black, fill=lightgray, ybar legend]
 coordinates {(AL2O3,24) (ALN,180) (Si3N4,70) (BeO,250) (Epoxid,3.0)      (Polimid,0.385) (ALSiC,200) (Al,237) (Cu,394) (Mo,138) (Si,148) (Au,317)};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Somehow I would like to have a minor grid at the y axis, and that it starts at 0 along with the x axis, and that the upper axis doesn't have a cross...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: What does "upper axis doesn't have a cross" mean?

Comment: @ThorstenDonig it should mean that the marks at the upper horizontal axis atays just in the box... I believe that is made with xtick{}, but I´m not sure...

Comment: No good idea. Imagine a situation where one or more bars go beyond the upper limit of the *y* domain. Then it would be good to have the ticks outside the axes for better orientation

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this approach is somewhat useful for you. The axes are put at the left and bottom and there is a minor grid for the *y* ticks. There are no `symbolic x coords` anymore and instead you now have explicit `xticklabels`. The double first and last ticks are gone.

The chemical compounds in the ticks of the abscissa have been formatted by »chemformula« from the »[chemmacros](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros)« bundle. The »[siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)« package helps to format the unit for the label of the ordinate.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
  per-mode=fraction
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=14cm,
      height=7cm,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      axis y line*=left,
      nodes near coords,
      legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1
      },
      xtick={1,2,...,12},
      xticklabels={\ch{AL2O3},\ch{ALN},\ch{Si3N4},\ch{BeO},Epoxid,Polyimid,\ch{ALSiC},\ch{Al},\ch{Cu},\ch{Mo},\ch{Si},\ch{Au}},
      x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
      ymin=0,
      ymax=500,
      ybar=5pt,
      bar width=0.4cm,
      ylabel={Thermoconductivity / \si{\W\per\m\per\K}},
      ymajorgrids=true,
      ytick={100,200,...,500}
    ]
      \addplot[color=black,fill=lightgray,ybar legend] coordinates {
        (1,24)
        (2,180)
        (3,70)
        (4,250)
        (5,3)
        (6,0.385)
        (7,200)
        (8,237)
        (9,394)
        (10,138)
        (11,148)
        (12,317)
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]